# Find an equation for the plane that passes through the following points.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

This problem comes from my Calculus III homework. There is an example from my textbook that has this same question, but I don't understand the solution. Here is the textbook example: 
[EXAMPLE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg0nU.jpg)

My question asks the same, except with the points (2, −1, 3), (0, 0, 5), and (5, 6, −1).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We would like to see what you have done so far, and where you need help.

Comment: Follow the same process, but with your points instead of the ones in the example. What, specifically, is the difficulty that you’re having in doing this?